# Delete a row from a datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to delete with jQuery a row selecting `id="data(Number)"` from a datatable how this. That's possible, or `id` would be better on `<tr>` tag, instead of `<td>` tag?

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Check</th>
            <th>Field_1</th>
            <th>Field_2</th>
            <th>Field_3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="dataTable">
        <tr>
            <td><input type='checkbox' id='data1'><br></td>
            <td>Field_1_Input1</td>
            <td>Field_2_Input1</td>
            <td>Field_3_Input1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type='checkbox' id='data2'><br></td>
            <td>Field_1_Input2</td>
            <td>Field_2_Input2</td>
            <td>Field_3_Input2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
 function removerow(number){
    $('#data'+number).closest('tr').remove();
}
```

and then you can call for example `removerow(2)` to delete row that has the input element with `id=data2`

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xLyxeg5f/)

**UPDATE** (from comments)

To get also the `td` elements text within the row with `$("#data"+i)` try:

```
$('#data' + number).parent().siblings().each(function () {
        console.log($(this).text());
});
```

[DEMO2](http://jsfiddle.net/xLyxeg5f/2/)

Comment: Thanks everybody. And what would be the target to select a data from a field? For example Field_1_Input1.

Comment: @oscarvady Which `td` especially do you want to target? In which row and in which column?

Comment: I want to get the content of a row, the fields 1,2 and 3 with the selector `$("#data"+i)`

Comment: I am trying with `.siblings()` and `.next()` but I am not be able.

Answer (score 3):

try the following -

1. First get the dataTable instance

> var oTable = $('#table_id').dataTable();

2. call below function to delete the row corresponding to selected

> oTable.fnDeleteRow(oTable.fnGetPosition(selected_tr));  // JQuery dataTable
>   function to delete the row from the table

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use this seletor `:eq(n)`

```
function deleteRow(number)
{
     $("tbody tr:eq(" + number")").remove();
}
```

this will remove row which number is selected, starting by 0.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example :-

```
 var table = $('#example').DataTable();

  $('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'img.icon-delete', function () {
    table
        .row( $(this).parents('tr') )
        .remove()
        .draw();
} );
```

Comment: You pasted that straight from the documentation without giving an example on how to use the code.

Answer (score 0):

using datatable API is easy to use and can help if you are using `paging` etc. which will update the page count on the document once row is removed.

```
// datatable intitalization.

$('#userInfo').DataTable({
        'paging': true,
        'lengthChange': true,
        "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],
        'searching': true,
        'info': true,
        'autoWidth': true,
        'stateSave': true,
        'ordering': true,
        'deferRender': true,
        columnDefs: [
            { targets: [4], orderable: false }
        ]
    });

    // function to remove datatable row.
    function RemoveDatatableRow(rowId){
       var row = $("#" + rowId);
       $("#userInfo").dataTable().fnDeleteRow(row);        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tableID = $('#dataTableInfoUser');
    var table = tableID.DataTable().rows().nodes();
    var rowCount = table.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
        var row = tableID.DataTable().row(i).node();
        var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
        if (null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
            tableID.dataTable().fnDeleteRow(i); 
            rowCount--;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please add some explaination as to why your code snippet solves the OP's problem. For more info [answer]